# Calculate average when all data is not there?

Tags: statistics

This is not a complex mathematical question, so I'm not sure if this is the right place to post.

We have a master database that includes data in 15-minute intervals. A sample from the master DB looks like the following:

```
EmpId           Value             DateTime
ABC123          5                 2017-03-16 01:00:00.000
ABC123          8                 2017-03-16 01:15:00.000
ABC123          1                 2017-03-16 01:30:00.000
ABC123          2                 2017-03-16 01:45:00.000
```

Since I need to get daily averages, I did a daily sum per EmpId. Something like this:

```
EmpId           Sales             DateTime             QuarterCount
ABC123          253               2017-03-16           96
ABC123          320               2017-03-17           96
ABC123          749               2017-03-18           96
ABC123          253               2017-03-19           93
ABC123          634               2017-03-20           87
ABC123          593               2017-03-21           96
ABC123          648               2017-03-22           89
ABC123          369               2017-03-23           96
```

So with all this data, I need to get a 7-day average for `2017-03-16` to `2017-03-22`. If they were all `96` (the amount 15-min quarters in a day), then it'd be easy: I just add all the sales for all 7 days and divide by 7.

But let's say that one (or more) of those days doesn't have all 96 quarters; in this example it would be 3/19, 3/20, 3/22. Would the average still be the total of all 7 days divided by 7?

Once I get the 7-day average per `EmpId`, I compare it with the last day (2017-03-23). If 3/23 had all 96 quarters, then it would be a valid comparison. But assuming that 3/23 only has 80 in column `QuarterCount`, would it be fair to compare my previous week average with the value from this last day?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question.  The end result is that if you take the average number of sales per day, it gives you the average number of sales per day and this is irregardless of how many quarterhours were spent on any individual day.  If you take the average number of sales per quarter hour, then you get the average number of sales per quarter hour.  Whichever average you want to take is the one you take... you say you want the average per day so continue as normal by totaling over all 7 days and divide by 7.

Comment: As I understand your problem, some of your days are 24 hour days and some days have fewer than 24 hours in the database (you weren't processing transactions for an hour or two).  Nonetheless if you want average daily sales, you should divide total sales by the number of days, even though some days more (or less) hours of business activity.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether the missing quarter-hour elements indicate (a) that there were no sales during that period, or (b) there may have been sales during that period, but just weren't reported.

In case (a), you're not missing any sales.  Just add up the total daily sales, and divide by seven.

In case (b), you are missing some sales, and you have to make an assumption, because you have incomplete data.  A simple (but perhaps unrealistic) assumption is that you would have sold at the same rate for those missing periods.  For March 20th, then, you could estimate that you sold

$$634 \times \frac{96}{87} \doteq 700$$

units.  Now you have an estimate of the full day's sales, and you can go back to case (a).